# C++ move semantics: why copy assignment operator=(&) is called instead of move assignment operator=(&&)?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, move, move-constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

struct SomeType {
  SomeType() {}

  SomeType(const SomeType &&other) {
    cout << "SomeType(SomeType&&)\n";
    *this = std::move(other);
  }

  void operator=(const SomeType &) {
    cout << "operator=(const SomeType&)\n";
  }

  void operator=(SomeType &&) {
    cout << "operator=(SomeType&&)\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  SomeType a;
  SomeType b(std::move(a));
  b = std::move(a);
  return 0;
}
```

I expect move constructor to call the move assignment operator. Here is the output of this program:

```
SomeType(SomeType&&)
operator=(const SomeType&)
operator=(SomeType&&)
```

As you can see, move assignment operator is successfully called, but not when assigning to `*this` inside move constructor. Why is this happening, can I fix it somehow?

Comment: `SomeType(const SomeType &&other)` - this is wrong

Comment: Remove the `const` from `const SomeType &&other`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your move constructor takes a `const SomeType&&` rather than a `SomeType&&`. You cannot call a function that takes a `SomeType&&` (your move constructor) with a value of type `const SomeType&&`.

Try making a move constructor that takes a `SomeType&&`.

Answer (score 5):

`std::move` casts to an r-value reference. So it casts `other` to `const SomeType &&`. This of course cannot bind to `SomeType &&`, so it falls back to `const SomeType &`.

Remove the `const` from the move constructor's parameter.