# Convince a constructor to move an object a parent's constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++20, perfect-forwarding

I've been attempting to forward an object to a parent without having the object copied. I cannot seem to be able to do this, and don't know why.

Here is an example of the kind of thing I would like to do. It does not compile, however.

```
class Initialisee {
    public:
        Initialisee() = default;
        Initialisee(const Initialisee&) = delete;
        Initialisee(Initialisee&&) = default;
};

class Parent {
    public:
        Parent(const Initialisee i) { }
};

class Child: public Parent {
    public:
        Child(const Initialisee i): Parent(std::move(i)) { }
};
```

This won't compile as, despite the `std::move()`, the child is still trying to copy-construct the object to pass it to the parent's constructor. I'm using MSVC 2019 (16.10.3) with the latest language features enabled.

Why won't it let me do this? Is this a bug or a quirk in the language? How could I write this in the correct way without having to implement a copy constructor on the object (which would be very expensive for the situations I actually want to do this for)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move operation is supposed to perform modification on the object to be moved from; but `i` is marked as `const` and can't be moved from. Especially, `const Initialisee` can't be bound to `Initialisee&&`, then it can't be passed to move constructor of `Initialisee`.

If your intent is to perform move operation it's better to declare it as rvalue-reference. e.g.

```
class Child: public Parent {
    public:
        Child(Initialisee&& i): Parent(std::move(i)) { }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot move out of `const` objects. It should be `Child(Initialisee i)`, not `Child(const Initialisee i)`.

I have encountered [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979643/c-move-semantics-why-copy-assignment-operator-is-called-instead-of-move-a) myself.